# Rgui command-line for sourcing R file

Tags: r, command-line

What command line option to use behind Rgui.exe for immediately sourcing an R source file? Instead of having to type `source("c:\MyGreatSource.R")` manually afterwards. Something like:

> Rgui.exe --source "c:\MyGreatSource.R"

Sounds like a simple question answered in any beginner's manual, but I couldn't find such an option anywhere.

Comment: Rscript.exe "c:\MyGreatSource.R"

Comment: It seems Rscript.exe executes the script and then closes. I want the GUI to stay open for me to work there.

Comment: This option does not exist with the R windows GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable solution, maybe others are interested. Again, what I like to do is to start the Rgui and work there. All my work environment and functions are defined in an R source file, which I constantly develop further during working. So each of my commands in the GUI starts with Load1(); where Load1 is a function which simply sources my R file, to update the changes I have just made. Obviously, Load1 is also defined in my R file, so I need to get it in the first place, without much effort. I have set the command-line options for neither loading nor saving the workplace; I don't like my old mess from the previous session with test variables and so.

However, my solution now is to just create a workplace RData file which only contains the definition of my Load1 function. This workplace file is easily loaded at every start by just adding its path into the command-line options `"D:\MyLoad1.RData"`

Answer (score 0):

I use a AutoHotkey Script

```
run,C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rgui.exe
WinWait,RGui (64-bit)
WinWaitActive,RGui (64-bit)

Sleep 100
Send,source("%1%")
Send,{enter}
```